# python os.path contains diacritic

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to get the user folder in windows (exactly: "**C:\Users\Guestík**") using python. The problem is, that it contains 'í' char. I always get this result: "**C:\Users\GuestÝk**".
I am trying to open database located in Desktop folder. Because of this charracter, i can not open it, because the path is not right. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you currently doing to get the profile directory?

Comment: You'll have to be particularly careful about this in Python 2.x, for which a lot of the standard library is limited to the ANSI codepage. Most of the problems are resolved by Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unicode table https://unicode-table.com/de/#latin-extended-a and then you can use escape characters like \u to describe this character. for example \u0170

sorry for my bad english.